# Fitting an equation to data

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, fitting, data

If I have the followind data:

```
data={{45, 2.93495}, {50, 2.94697}, {55, 1.9801}, {60,0.734437}, {65, -0.0128219}, {70, -0.695535}, {75,-1.35939}, {80,-1.47567}}
```

where the x values are Temperature in Celsius (T) and the y values are log10 of time (t).

**Question:**

1. How can I fit  the following equation to the data  and find the fitting parameters `K1` and `K2`?

[image]

where `log (tind)` is the log in base 10 of time (y axis of my data), `T` is the x axis of my data and `T0=259.246 (*Kelvin*)`, `B=2595.89`, `Tm=433.15 (*Kelvin*)`

I have been trying the following but it does not work:

```
T0=259.246 (*Kelvin*); 
B=2595.89; 
Tm=433.15 (*Kelvin*);
    eq = k1 - 2*Log10[T] + (k2/(2.303*T^3*(Tm - T)^2)) + 0.75*(B/(2.303*(T - T0))) (*T would be the x axis of my data*)
    nlmtind = NonlinearModelFit[data, eq, {k1, k2}, x]
```

**Notice that the x axis should be converted to kelvin (+273.15) for consistency of units**

Comment: In your code `Tm,T0,B` are not specified and `x` in the fit is `T`, I presume. This works: `nlmtind = NonlinearModelFit[data, eq, {k1, k2, Tm, T0, B}, T]`

Comment: @Andrzej thanks for your comment. `Tm`, `T0` and `B` are numbers shown above. I put this numbers in the code to make it more specific. Unfortunately, your suggestions is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = {{45, 2.93495}, {50, 2.94697}, {55, 1.9801}, {60, 
    0.734437}, {65, -0.0128219}, {70, -0.695535}, {75, -1.35939}, \
{80, -1.47567}};
y = k1 - 2 Log[x, 10] + k2/2.303/(x^3 (Tm - x)^2) + 
    0.75 B/2.303/(x - T0) /. {T0 -> 259.246, B -> 2595.89, 
    Tm -> 433.15};

fun[x_] = NonlinearModelFit[data, y, {k1, k2}, x] // Normal;

Plot[fun[x], {x, 45, 80}, Epilog -> Point[data]]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

If you want to force the k1 and k2 to be positive, the fit will be horrible:

```
t = NonlinearModelFit[data, {y, k1 > 0, k2 > 0}, {k1, k2}, x];
t["BestFitParameters"]

(* {k1 -> 11.496, k2 -> 1874.25} *)
```

k1 and k2 are now positive, but the fit is bad:

```
fun[x_] = t // Normal
Plot[fun[x], {x, 45, 80}, Epilog -> Point[data], PlotRange -> {-1, 7}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Daniel! One quick question: How can I make `k1` and `k2` be greater than 0? I am trying this from your code: `NonlinearModelFit[data, y, {{k1>0}, {k2>0}}, x]` but it does not seem to force those fitting parameters to be greater than 0

Comment: Try `fun[x_] = NonlinearModelFit[data, {y, k1 > 0, k2 > 0}, {k1, k2}, x]`

Comment: I made an addendum to my answer. To request the parameters to be positive gives an unusable fit.